# Octave: Boolean AND returns wrong number

Tags: boolean, octave, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, octave-gui

I am trying for several hours to calculate a boolean AND operation in Octave.
It return a wrong number.

I want to calculate following numbers:
result = 4037 & 63
result should be 5 but i get 1.

I also tried result = and(4037, 63) but i get 1 again

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your first clue to what is going wrong is that in your example, the type of `result` is logical rather than double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are not meant to be used for bitwise operations. Instead, you should use **bitand** function:

```
result = bitand(4037, 63)
```